# Single Instance vs Multiple Instances on google cloud for wordpress websites on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, wordpress, multiple-instances

I'm trying to host many wordpress websites on google cloud and from what I could learn, everytime I go to the marketplace and get the wordpress VM I have to create a new instance.

I know that I can use a single instance for multiple websites, but I cannot find any place that tells me how to do so. Is there an article or video that shows me how to do it?  But before that, do you think it is even worth it having one instance for many websites?

The majority of websites that I make are e-commerces. From what I've been able to learn so far, for every new website I have to create a new project and I have to create a new instance for each project.

I belive that having one big instance is easier to manage, but how do I do that?

Comment: Duplicate of [Hosting diferent wordpress websites on google cloud](https://serverfault.com/questions/1037086/hosting-diferent-wordpress-websites-on-google-cloud)

Comment: Ignoring Google Cloud, it's not difficult to run multiple Wordpress websites on one computer / VM. You set up Wordpress individually for each site, as while multi-site is possible it doesn't work very well. Then you configure your web server to point at the correct Wordpress instance for each domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your post does not completely describe your scenario, so I'll give you some insights in a way you can search further on this subject:

1. Take a look at this discussion: [Best way to make multiple sites](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/best-way-to-make-multiple-sites/)
   So you can go with having completely separate installations that will multiply your maintenance as well, or create a Network and easier the maintenance part, if that fits your scenario
2. Another option to be considered for your needs is having one container per website, which sounds good to me as well:
   https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress

Depending on your scenario and traffic, you can consider hosting each site/container on Google Cloud Run.
Although you'd still have to maintain security updates for Wordpress, that can be sorted out with a pipeline to build and deploy your new updated images.

3. Case you have a lot of websites and container images, deploying it all on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) is one option to consider for high availability and scaling your websites

**Edit**

4. GCP Marketplace also have Multisite/Multi-tier Wordpress images, so you can get this option as well